# Send faxes to a French fax number free of charge

Tags: gratis, fax

I am looking for a program, user script or web service that can send faxes to a French fax number free of charge.

Any operating system, browser and license is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [MondialFax](https://mondialfax.com/en/). Runs in your browser, enables you to upload .pdfs and send them to a fax number in France and it seems to be free.